# Docker-compose use env_file variables in the command

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a docker-file for a selenium grid that is able to change the nodes based on an environment variable.

```
selenoida:
  image: "aerokube/selenoid:latest"
  container_name: selenoid
  network_mode: bridge
  ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:4444:4444"
  volumes:
    - ".:/etc/selenoid"
    - "./target:/output"
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    - "./target:/opt/selenoid/video"
  environment:
    - "OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=$PWD/target"
  env_file:
    - variables.env
  command: ["-limit", "$NODES","-enable-file-upload", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video"]
```

But looks like the `command` is not able to use variables. I tested with `${NODES}`, `NODES`.

Any ideas on how to use env variables set from a file in commands?

Comment: Use $${NODES} so that Docker does not try to interpret the variable

Comment: Got the same result, is not getting the value from the variable

Comment: interesting... I assume the NODES var is defined in variables.env.... This is how I use an environment variable to start ` redis: entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "redis-server --appendonly yes --requirepass $${REDIS_PASS}"] `

Comment: yea, is defined in variables.env, but looks like is something about the `command` instruction ?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I completely forgot that the command in exec form will not invoke the shell to expand the variables. My bad. You can try using the command in shell form, or just overwrite the entrypoint with something like `entrypoint: [""sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/selenoid -listen :4444 -conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json -video-output-dir /opt/selenoid/video/ -enable-file-upload -limit $${NODES}"] `

Comment: Wow worked perfect! just a question why this `/usr/bin/selenoid/` I mean why this route if the container is named selenoida and is not set on that path

Comment: I looked at their dockerfile in GitHub and that is the path they used there :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228974/discussion-between-nonyck-and-camba1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command in exec form will not invoke the shell to expand the variables.

You can try using the command in shell form, or just overwrite the entrypoint with:

```
entrypoint: [""sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/selenoid -listen :4444 -conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json -video-output-dir /opt/selenoid/video/ -enable-file-upload -limit $${NODES}"]
```